# Java // The operator + is undefined for the argument types String, void

Tags: java, operators, minecraft-forge

So this is a project my son is doing and he asked me to help him however I currently have 0 knowledge on "Java" therefore I am posting the question he wants answered.

"I am trying to make a mod for "Minecraft" and when writing it an error came up that I am struggling to understand any ideas??"

//Class HypedMetaItemBlock

```
import net.minecraft.*;

public class HypedMetaItemBlock extends ItemBlock {
public HypedMetaItemBlock(Block block) {
    super(block);
    setHasSubtypes(true);

}

@Override
public String getUnlocalizedName(ItemStack stack) {
    String name = "tile." + ((IHypedMetaBlock)Block.getBlockFromItem(stack.getItem())).getNames()[stack.getMetadata()] + ((IHypedMetaBlock)Block.getBlockFromItem(stack.getItem())).getSuffix();    
    return name;
}

@Override
public int getMetadata(int par1) {
    return par1;
     }
}
```

Here is the class for IHypedMetaBlock incase you need it

```
public interface IHypedMetaBlock {

public void addNames();
public void getSuffix();
public String[] getNames();

}
```

Comment: `((IHypedMetaBlock)Block.getBlockFromItem(stack.getItem())).getSuffix()` returns nothing. You can't append nothing to a String.

Comment: @Stephen C Thank you for the advice. Will inform him to grow up and stop acting like a child

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, Java does not *know* what to do when you use the `+` operator on a `String` and `void` type.

The main issue appears to be this method: `getSuffix()`. That method is `void`, meaning that it does not return anything. This violates the Java naming conventions, since usually, `getXX` methods return something.

You will need to either make sure that `getSuffix()` returns something, or else, rethink your approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help just going to tell my son  :)

Answer (score 0):

The getSuffix method is currently returning a void.  My guess is that it shouldn't be returning a void.  Just from the method name, it sounds like it should be returning a String.

But if it's the case that it really should be returning a void, then you can't use the method result as a String.